# SSIS string truncation error

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, truncation

I have a SQL Server 2005 SP2 database which has a table with a `poc_resp_city` attribute which is `nvarchar(35)`.

It was changed to `nvarchar(80)` 2 months ago without aligning the very same attribute in the data warehouse. (which still has `nvarchar(35)` )

The SSIS data loading package (after two months of proper working) now gives back package failure every time I run it with the following error:

> There was an error with output column "poc_resp_city" (2250) on output
>   "OLE DB Source Output" (11). The column status returned was: "Text was
>   truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code
>   page.".    There was an error with output column "poc_resp_city"
>   (2250) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11). The column status
>   returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no
>   match in the target code page.".
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on
>   component "Source Table" (1) returned error code 0xC020902A.  The
>   component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

Neither the package nor the databases were modified regarding this issue. I know that I could ignore this error or I could make the arrangements to make sure it's working but I want to provide a proper and acceptable answer why this error appears 2 months after the modification? Because maybe I miss an important step in this situation.

Important note: I don't have even a single record which has more than 35 characters so truncation never occurs. (this warning belongs to some kind of an SSIS validation step)

Now I think that maybe after a period of time, SSIS package recompiles itself and now it sees this misalignment in its metadata (35 =/= 80) and because `TruncationRowDisposition` attribute is set to `RD_FailComponent`, it fails the component.

And I would exclude the code page option because every database column is `nvarchar`, not `varchar`, so this shouldn't be the case.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check MAX(LEN()) in the source table?  I'd guess you somehow picked a record over 35 characters, maybe unprintables or trailing spaces.  That seems more likely than the spontaneous recompile explanation, though SSIS 2005 is rather old and always had more weird behavior than 2008 or 2012.

Comment: I checked it and checked LEN(city+'a') too to ignore white spaces. (because LEN('aa') and LEN('aa    ') gives back the same value. And there is no record which goes above 35

Comment: I really think you're mistaken. This is not a validation error, and the fact that it simply appeared after some time strongly indicates that someone just happened to enter an amount of data that was longer than 35. If you really want to get to the bottom of it, follow the advice below and run the package and isolate the data row(s) causing the issue (by reproducing the issue then divide and conquer to find the data). When you isolate the data row(s) it'll all become clear.

Comment: If you're convinced absolutely nothing could have been modified then that _only_ leaves the data in the database as the culprit because end users can modify that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refresh size of column:

1. With right button push on `OLE DB Source -> Show Advanced Editor`
2. Choose `Input and Output Properties` tab -> `Ole DB Source Output` -> `Output Columns`
3. In the right panel `Length` row insert your new size.
4. Push `OK`

[image: Show Advanced Editor]

Or you can copy your query from `OLE DB Source`, delete `OLE DB Source`, insert new `OLE DB Source` and paste query. This gonna automaticily refresh your columns.

Just remember what there are probably more element in Dataflow where you need to edit length of your column, like `Data Converion`...

Comment: Yes, I know that I can make this work by using advanced editor and setting the data length to the proper one.
But from the customer's point of view, I have to give a correct reason why this error shows up in SSIS after 2 months of the misalignments.

Comment: You can split a query data in half and watch if error raises.  Then split again where the error is in half till you find one row which raise error:)

Comment: There is no SQL Server error. This error only shows up by the SSIS's metadata validation task.

Comment: I guess you never found out why the error only occurred after two months?